# vscodeで急に文字？というか画面が急に小さくなりました

Tags: vscode

vscodeで急に文字？というか画面が急に小さくなりました。できるだけ早めに回答お願いします！
めちゃくちゃ見にくいと思いますがお願いします！

このままだと作業が全くできないのでなるべく早く対処法を教えてください。お願いします！

[image]

Comment: これらの記事あたりでしょうかね？[VS Codeでフォントを拡大／縮小するには](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/1811/30/news032.html), [Visual Studio Code | コードの拡大・縮小を有効にする設定](https://1-notes.com/visual-studio-code-mouse-wheel-zoom/)

Comment: @kunif さん、回答でコメントを行うと特に初心者の方には混乱のもとになります。なるべく回答欄の利用をご検討ください。

Comment: 質問者さん、一般論として質問サイトで回答を催促するような情報を最初に書いても、回答者には役に立ちません。人によっては回答者の労力をないがしろにしているとみなされる場合もあるので今後ご注意ください。また、そのような情報よりも、質問者さんが困るに至ったまでの詳しい情報の方が重要です。たとえばお使いの OS の情報や心当たりのある操作、自分で試してみたが上手くいかなかったことなどが質問文に載っていると回答がしやすく、結果として解決までの時間が短くなります。次ご質問なさるときの参考にしてみてください。

Comment: ユーザーではなく未確認なので情報として出してみました。付いた回答を見ると結局ずれていた感じですが。

Comment: すこしアプローチがちがうようにはみえるものの本質的にはかわりなく、ずれているわけでもなさそうですね(今回のものについては)。が、そもそも「ユーザーではなく未確認なので」というコンテキストを失っていてはたとえそれがコメントであろうが回答であろうがみたひとには「だからそうしている」ということは伝わりませんし、むしろそれが明示されていれば回答として投稿されているほうがいいまである場合もあります。

Comment: @nekketsuuu  さん　かなり焦っていて、時間もなかったので催促してしまう形になりました。自分なりに調べて片っ端から試してみたんですが、どれもできなかったので質問させていただきました。質問するために始めた初心者で何を書けばいいのかわからずとりあえず質問をしてみたという感じです。以後気を付けます。そして回答本当にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

VSCodeのデフォルトショートカットキーの<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>で縮小、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>(日本語キーボードでは<kbd>;</kbd>、USでは<kbd>=</kbd>)で拡大です。(<kbd>Shift</kbd>はいりません)
また、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>(テンキー)で拡大縮小のリセットです。

Comment: 返信遅れてしまい申し訳ありません。自分なりにいろいろ調べて試してみたのですがどんどん小さくなってしまい焦っていました。本当に助かりました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

ショートカットキーを押すなどしてズームアウトしたときの挙動に見えます。ズームインすれば元に戻ります。

スクリーンショットからは Windows のように見えるので、デフォルトのままであれば <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>（あるいは <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>）でズームインできます。逆に <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> でズームアウトです。

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_display

Comment: 返信遅れてしまって申し訳ありません。自分なりに調べて試していたんですが、どんどん悪化してしまい、手詰まっていました。助かりました。ありがとうございます！